# Apache VirtualHost with SSL Not Found

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, virtualhost

I setup 3 virtual hosts on port 80. Everything is fine.
Now I would setup the SSL version of these virtual hosts. All works except the main `DocumentRoot`.

```
Listen 80 
ServerName www.mydomain.com
NameVirtualHost *:80
NameVirtualHost *:443
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
    DocumentRoot /home/someone/www/work
    ServerName work.example.com
    <Directory /home/someone/www/work>
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
    DocumentRoot /home/someone/www
    ServerName www.example.com
    <Directory /home/someone/www>
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
    DocumentRoot /home/someone/www/work
    ServerName work.example.com
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /home/someone/ssl-certs-keys/c1.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /home/someone/ssl-certs-keys/c1.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /home/someone/ssl-certs-keys/c1.i.crt

    <Directory /home/someone/www/work>
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
    DocumentRoot /home/someone/www
    ServerName www.example.com
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /home/someone/ssl-certs-keys/c1.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /home/someone/ssl-certs-keys/c1.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /home/someone/ssl-certs-keys/c1.i.crt
    <Directory /home/someone/www>
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Now, no problem if I connect to `www.example.com`, `work.example.com`, `https://work.example.com`. The only problem is that when I connect to `https://www.example.com`, I get `The requested URL / was not found on this server`".

If I add somewhere in httpd.conf DocumentRoot /home/someone/www the pages there are loaded... Why, for 443, I have to add `DocumentRoot`, and why the `VirtualHost` for the main domain is not read.

**[EDIT]**

As for a comment, if I type httpd -S

```
VirtualHost configuration:

wildcard NameVirtualHosts and _default_ servers:
*:443                  is a NameVirtualHost
         default server www.mydomain.com (/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf:74)
         port 443 namevhost www.mydomain.com (/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf:74)
         port 443 namevhost work.mydomain.com (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:1074)
```

Why the default server points to ssl.conf and not httpd.conf?

Comment: What does your apache log say?

Comment: in ssl_error_log "File does not exist: /etc/httpd/htdocs"

Comment: There's something wrong with your config but I can't find it from what you've posted here. There might be a typo that's hidden by your obfuscation, for instance. You can try doing `httpd -S` to show the virtualhost settings and include them into the question.

Answer (score 2):

Solved. The problem is `ServerName` at the head of `httpd.conf`.
It should be removed if the main domain is defined as `VirtualHost`.

Comment: I would use the name of the server instead, but that's largely a matter of taste. (For instance, my personal web server is called "sameen" which I use as the main ServerName, and has a virtual host with "www.example.com".)

Comment: Well, if I do not delete the ServerName outside the VirtualHost blocks, the problem arises.

Answer (score -1):

I may have the solution to your problem.
It may be due to your folder permission.
Simple using your FTP client go to /etc/letsencrpyt make sure that every of your folders permissions are set to 0755 (do so by right clicking and select file permission).

Comment: Nothing in this question mentions Let's Encrypt or trouble accessing said folders.